# How do I detect if a MarshalByRefObject is local or remote?

Tags: .net, remoting, marshalbyrefobject

In other words, how do I tell if I have a reference to a TransparentProxy or a local object?

Comment: Shouldn't your code really *know* a-priori whether you're on the local or remote side though?

Comment: Also, does `obj.GeType().IsMarshalByRef` or `obj.GetType().IsContextful` yield anything useful perchance?

Comment: I actually am debugging trouble with objects crossing the boundary unexpectedly (via serialization), so I wanted to write an Assert that a certain object is a TP.

Comment: Ah right, fair enough then. How about either of those solutions I just suggested though?

Comment: @Noldorin, I think if `obj` has type `X`, `GetType()` would return the same thing (`typeof(X)`) regardless of whether `obj` is local or remote.

Comment: You'd think that, but actually no; proxies are weird things. They appear the same for most purposes though.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [IsTransparentProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingservices.istransparentproxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method found in [RemotingServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t76ywb4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this fun little trick:

```
bool fIsTransparentProxy = ((myTransparentObject as MarshalByRefObject) == null);
```

When I attempted to convert a transparent proxy to MarshalByRefObject, it returned null. I tested this in VB, since that's where all my proxies are, but hopefully the same behavior holds true in C#.

Also note that Visual Studio debugger knows which is which, but I couldn't figure out how to get code that produces the same results (hovering over a TP object in VS shows `System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy` as the class type, but this is an internal sealed class).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The cast succeeds when the object is a TP. All my objects are in the same process though (different AppDomain).